# Deploying a windows phone app to an actual device does not work but still working with emulators. Error DEP6500 and DEP6100

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I tried several times to deploy my app to a Windows Phone device using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and that doesn't work and gives me an error message: 
**" DEP6500 : A specified communication resource(port) is already in use by another application"** ,
but it works well with emulators! why? also I have done the following to make deploying to a device works well, but unfortunately without a result:

- Trying two versions of Visual Studio, Ultimate 2013 Update 4 and Enterprise 2015
- Restarting the service "Windows Phone IP over USB Transport" (IpOverUsbSvc)
- Resetting my windows phone device
- Plugging the device in different USB ports
- Trying different projects types: Windows Phone Silverlight apps and WinRT apps
- Restoring defaults in Windows Firewall
- Signing out the current user account, and signing in to another user account, and then running VS and deploying a new app to the device, and I got another error message different to the latter message: **" DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Getting endpoint address' "**

What is this problem that prevents deploying apps to an actual Windows Phone device?

Answer (score 0):

When connect the phone to PC, close every program that pop up, so it won't use the port, then check for the following

- Can you access your files and folder inside the phone on Windows Explorer?
- Does the charging icon on the phone show up, and the phone start charging?

These things maybe unstable, which indicate that your USB Cable is broken, change to a new USB Cable and check again.

Some other things to try

- Connect to a different PC
- Use a different phone to connect to the same PC and the different one (the best case is you already know it's working)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows phone 8 for testing then update your phone to windows phone 8.1

Or

Use Visual studio 2012..